# Different of features and class and what is relationship?

Tags: machine-learning

When I research Machine Learning, I saw: " **assume I have 1000 features and 10 observations from two classes as a training set, and 10 other observations as a testing set**". I just think features and classes are the same mean so when I read it, I'm very confused.

In machine learning, feature different with classes? or sometimes they have same and different?

Answer (score 0):

Classes are different categories into which you can separate your data.

Features are different attributes that a piece of data can have. These features may be helpful in deciding what class a piece of data belongs to.

Imagine you have a set of pictures of dogs and birds, and you want to separate them into those two categories.

In this case, your classes are (1) dog and (2) bird.

The features would be anything that can apply to one category or the other (or both). For example, a list of features for dog might be:

```
dog_features = ["has fur", "has tongue", "has four legs", "is animal"]
```

and a list of features for bird might be:

```
bird_features = ["has feathers", "has beak", "has wings", "is animal"]
```